# Module and localization of injective

Tags: commutative-algebra, injective-module

Let $K$ be a field and let $I$ be an infinite set. We put $R = K^I$ (copies of $K$), $J = K^{(I)}$ and $S = \{1 − r \mid r ∈ J\}$. Then $R/J\simeq S^{−1}R$, $R$ is an injective module, but $R/J$ is not injective.

> My questions are:
>   1) $R$ is injective as $K-$module or $R-$module?
>
> 2) $R/J$ is not injective as $K-$module or $R-$module?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I sent an image ( but I will use it next time thanks.)